# Merge rows from $.each response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using the following code to present products that comes from an ajax response. My issue is that the table has many products with the same image. So I would like to find all the products with the same rec.Photo . Then I will present on one row the image and say that “we have variant of similar products click on the photo to see more… “
My issue is :
a)how I can find all the products with the same photo
b)how can I present on one row “see more similar products…” without destroy the loop

```
  $.each(response, function (i, rec) {
                                 if (i > 0) {

                                     strproductlist += '<div class="gridItem listView">';
                                     strproductlist += ' <div class="gridItemContent">';
                                     strproductlist += '<div class="productPhoto">';
                                     strproductlist += '<a title="' + rec.ProductName + '"  href="ProductDetails.aspx?productid=' +
 rec.ProductID + '">';
                                     strproductlist += '<img alt="' + rec.ProductName + '" src="' + rec.Photo + '">';
                                     strproductlist += '</a>';
                                     strproductlist += '</div>';
                                     strproductlist += '<div class="listViewProductDet">';
                                     strproductlist += '<h2>';
                                     strproductlist += '<a title="" href="ProductDetails.aspx?productid=' + rec.ProductID + '">' +
 rec.ProductName + '</a>';
                                     strproductlist += '</h2>';
                                     strproductlist += '<p class="productCode">' + rec.ProductCode + '</p>';
                                     strproductlist += '<ul class="fieldlist">';

    strproductlist += '</div>';
                                     strproductlist += '</div>';
                                     strproductlist += '</div>';
                                 }
```

//Edit
I am writing four sample records that presents 3 records with the same image

> -------- ProductID=1 ProductName=product1 Photo=~/products/product1.jpg ProductCode=001
>   -------- ProductID=2 ProductName=product2 Photo=~/products/product1.jpg ProductCode=002
>   -------- ProductID=3 ProductName=product3 Photo=~/products/product1.jpg ProductCode=003
>   -------- ProductID=4 ProductName=product4 Photo=~/products/product2.jpg ProductCode=004

Comment: same image will have **same image name**?

Comment: yes many products have the same image with the same image name

Comment: and stored in different paths? `rec.Photo` might come same for multiple times??

Comment: no the rec.Photo is the same. So i have the same photo for many products. What i would like to do is just present one of these products and say that we have many simmilar products like this. Just that.

Comment: This can be done!! But I need more code to work up with!! can you provide sample data or a demo would be great!??

Comment: I have edit my post. Please check

Comment: I want the rendering part!! how you are doing it??

Answer (score 0):

I hope below is what you are looking for. What I am doing is I am appending `elements` to `body` on each step so that I can identify whether the particular `image` with same `url` is present in body and if yes then don't render it and render what you need to like **<kbd>view more similar products</kbd>**. For time being I have just displayed an `alert` saying **<kbd>Image is present</kbd>**. You can write logic of displaying <kbd>**view similar products**</kbd> in that part!!

**[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3tmdc95h/2/)**

```js
var data=[
    {"ProductID":"1","ProductName":"product1", "Photo":"https://www.runtastic.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/r/orbit_with_clip_en_1.png","ProductCode":"001"},
    {"ProductID":"2","ProductName":"product2", "Photo":"https://truegamers.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/_/3_83_6.jpg","ProductCode":"002"},
    {"ProductID":"3","ProductName":"product3", "Photo":"https://www.runtastic.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/r/orbit_with_clip_en_1.png","ProductCode":"003"},
    {"ProductID":"4","ProductName":"product4", "Photo":"https://truegamers.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/_/3_83_6.jpg","ProductCode":"004"}
];

$.each(data, function (i, rec) {
    var strproductlist="";
    
    var imgname=rec.Photo;
    if($('.gridItem img[src="'+imgname+'"]').length)
    {
       alert('image present');
    }
    else
    {
        strproductlist += '<div class="gridItem listView">';
        strproductlist += '<div class="gridItemContent">';
        strproductlist += '<div class="productPhoto">';
        strproductlist += '<a title="' + rec.ProductName + '"  href="ProductDetails.aspx?productid=' +
 rec.ProductID + '">';
        strproductlist += '<img alt="' + rec.ProductName + '" src="' + rec.Photo + '">';
        strproductlist += '</a>';
        strproductlist += '</div>';
        strproductlist += '<div class="listViewProductDet">';
        strproductlist += '<h2>';
        strproductlist += '<a title="" href="ProductDetails.aspx?productid=' + rec.ProductID + '">' +
 rec.ProductName + '</a>';
         strproductlist += '</h2>';
         strproductlist += '<p class="productCode">' + rec.ProductCode + '</p>';
         strproductlist += '<ul class="fieldlist">';
         strproductlist += '</div>';
         strproductlist += '</div>';
         strproductlist += '</div>';
         $('body').append(strproductlist)
    
    }
    
});
```

```css
img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.gridItem{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3tmdc95h/3/)**

Inside your `if` instead of alert I've written `console.log` which shows the `parent` that contains that `image`

```
if($('.gridItem img[src="'+imgname+'"]').length)
{
       console.log($('.gridItem img[src="'+imgname+'"]').closest('.gridItem'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how can find the specific row that the image is already apear and write on this row what i want?

Comment: @focus Updated answer!! Check and let me know!!

Comment: The "if" statment that you have add on your update it gives always false so the statment continue to execute always the "else"

Comment: do one thing!! just take `console.log` from update and use if from my last code itself. but I haven't changed anything other than replacing alert!! and its working fine in fiddle demo given in update!!

Comment: The issue is on my render...  $("#productsListing").html(strproductlist); The table is render after the loop has finish so when we search for any same photo on the grid the answer is false because the grid is empty the time that we are looking...

Comment: That's what I've suggested to do!! Change the rendering inside `$.each`  and declare `strproductlist` inside `each`